# "Unrecognised emulation mode: ain" when compiling with gcc on Ubuntu

Tags: c++

Consider the following code lying in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Compilation with `g++ main.cpp -o -main` fails:

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: ain
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm on a 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS running in WSL2. GCC's version is

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

How do I make this Hello World compile?

Comment: Although the question is caused by a typo, I consider this to be a popular typo (hence useful to other users) because `main` is a popular name for the target executable. I was not able to google the `unrecognized emulation mode: ain` error this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've accidentally typed a dash before specifying your output file: it should be `-o main`, not `-o -main`, so the full command line is `g++ main.cpp -o main`

GCC has a `-m` key which allows specifying target machine architecture. For some reason, even when `-main` immediately follows `-o`, GCC still checks that the architecture (`ain` in case of `-main`) exists.

For example, if I compile with `g++ main.cpp -o -melf_x86_64`, I get an executable named `-melf_x86_64` (to remove it, use `rm ./-melf_x86_64` instead of `rm -melf_x86_64`). However, if I try `g++ main.cpp -o -mi386`, I get some compilation errors because I don't have 32-bit C++ standard library installed.

Looks like a bug to me: it simultaneously changes target architecture AND changes output file name. I've just opened [GCC issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103362) and [LLVM issue](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52583) (clang is affected as well).

UPD: actually looks [like a bug in LD](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28619).

Comment: It seem that `-l` is also affect: `-o -l` yields an executable named `"--library=` for me on msys2's gcc (but not Ubuntu).